# How not to depend on user@localhost on remote working server when checking current user?

Tags: mysql

I created a trigger in mysql 8 and as I log into the system(home laptop with kubuntu 22/apache2) as mysqldev I try to restrict some
operations, except "superadmin" user,
so I have in trigger :

```
create definer = mysqldev@localhost trigger trigger_update
    after update
    on products
    for each row
BEGIN

DECLARE newStatus varchar(1);

SET newStatus = NEW.status;

SET @currentUser = CURRENT_USER();

IF newStatus = 'D' THEN -- only superadmin can edit completed task
        IF (@currentUser != 'superadmin') THEN
            SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'
                SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Only superadmin can edit completed task !';
END IF;
```

But I suppose that now I have mysqldev@localhost on remote working server it would not be 'superadmin@localhost' as remote server could have another name and do not wnt to depend on it.

function USER() - also returns

> mysqldev@localhost value

How that can be salved ?

Comment: As it is written `IF (@currentUser != 'superadmin')` will always be true because  `CURRENT_USER()` even if superadim is logged will give `superadmin@....`. I don't seem to understand what issue are you facing

Comment: I mean that "@localhost" is now on my local server. But when I push the code remote server could have other name. Do not know how that  can be salved....Maybe some substr functions can be used?

Comment: Yes , use `SET @currentUser =SUBSTRING_INDEX(CURRENT_USER(),'@',1)`

Comment: Why not add a user column to your table, first you would see who changed it last and wouldn't need to add all the users to the details abase

Comment: @Ergest Basha, would CURRENT_USER() ALWAYS returns value with  '@'  ?

Comment: @mstdmstd yes.  A user has always a host which comes after `@`. https://dbfiddle.uk/H9_ug0KQ

Comment: @Ergest Basha, would you write it as answer - to accept it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every user is followed by a host which comes after the `@`.

For example,

```
select current_user();
```

Result

```
| current_user() |
+----------------+
| root@localhost |
```

In your case to have a deterministic result , use

```
select SUBSTRING_INDEX(CURRENT_USER(),'@',1) as user_name;
```

Result

```
| user_name |
+-----------+
| root      |
```

---

Replace

```
SET @currentUser = CURRENT_USER();
```

with

```
SET @currentUser = SUBSTRING_INDEX(CURRENT_USER(),'@',1) ;
```